# Outlook StickyNote Color in Outlook on the web

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in that needs to create Outlook Notes (StickyNote). Since the Outlook REST API and Graph API don't support this I'm using Exchange Web Services (EWS). I can successfully create a note like this:

```
createNote(subject, body) {
    var xml =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
        '               xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
        '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
        '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">' +
        '      <m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
        '        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="notes" />' +
        '      </m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
        '      <m:Items>' +
        '        <t:Message>' +
        '          <t:ItemClass>IPM.StickyNote</t:ItemClass>' +
        '          <t:Subject>' + subject + '</t:Subject>' +
        '          <t:Body>' + body + '</t:Body> ' +
        '          <t:ExtendedProperty>' +
        '            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="0006200E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" PropertyId="35584" PropertyType="Integer" />' +
        '            <t:Value>1</t:Value>' +
        '          </t:ExtendedProperty>' +
        '        </t:Message>' +
        '      </m:Items>' +
        '    </m:CreateItem>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(xml, function (result) {
        if (result === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
            console.log(result.value);
    });
}
```

The extended property is to set the color of the note (0 = blue, 1 = green, 2 = pink, 3 = yellow, 4 = white). However, this only works in the Outlook desktop app. Outlook on the web shows all the notes as gray. I assume it uses another custom property to set the color. Anyone knows how the note color can be set in Outlook on the web?

Comment: Do you get the same results with a pure EWS without office add-ins involved?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi and look at the following properties

[image]

If i set the color in the JSON _Note property which is a JSON string like

```html
{"schemaVersion":"beta","documentModifiedAt":"2021-01-13T02:18:33.411Z","document":{"type":"document","blocks":[{"type":"paragraph","id":"ej73vbcb-c65a-4a4e-944a-243f540eaa16","content":[{"text":"test1","styles":null}],"blockStyles":[{"textDirection":"ltr"}]},{"type":"paragraph","id":"55pcod81-f62a-4cc8-be0b-ea28404bd60b","content":null}]},"createdWithLocalId":"1f202a39-cc90-4812-b7ff-9beef48af549","createdWithLocalId@Is.Queryable":"True","createdByApp":"OWA","createdByApp@Is.Queryable":"True","color":4,"color@Is.Queryable":"True","documentModifiedAt@Is.Queryable":"True","#type.documentModifiedAt":"DateTime","#type.createdWithLocalId":"String","#type.createdByApp":"String","#type.color":"Int32"}
```

and then refresh OWA that will change the color of the note in OWA. Changing the #color property doesn't seem to do anything. Some problems though this is going to be unsupported, the colors don't sync between Outlook Desktop and OWA at the moment the integers values don't event align eg 3 is Yellow in the Outlook Desktop and Pink in OWA. It maybe worth asking another question on Q&A https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-outlook-itpro.html (don't mentioned anything about trying to use code) and just ask why the colors don't sync between the Desktop and OWA when you use the client.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I can confirm that this is the property used to set the color. However setting the value through EWS seems to be challenging. I can set it exactly as your json but the color does not change. Here comes the strange part. If I later open the property in OutlookSpy and click to SaveChanges, without actually changing anything, the color changes to what I previously set in my EWS.

Comment: This is how i set the property:
<t:ExtendedProperty>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="E550B918-9859-47B9-8095-97E4E72F1926" PropertyName="IOpenTypedFacet.Com_Microsoft_Note" PropertyType="String" />
  <t:Value>{ ... json ... }</t:Value>
</t:ExtendedProperty>

Comment: I've included a sample that i can use to create and modify an existing Note and that seems to work. You need to make sure that you set both the color and note property when updating and make sure the extensions property is set during creation. If you look at what OWA is doing its using its own private API https://substrate.office.com/NotesClient/api/v2.0/me/notes to do this. So you need to be a little careful as this then gets used by the local Windows 10 sticknote app to sync down locally etc so don't duplicate things like Id's or you might find things start crashing etc if that app used.